# How can I disable animating a specific state change on a subview in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

My ContentView includes a view (MapCardView) that is pushed outside of the visible area on launch and partly slides back in from the bottom (together with its subviews) when an annotation on the map view (MapKitView) is selected (much like in the Maps app):

```
@State private var showAnnotationCard = false
@State private var annotation: MKAnnotation?
private let kBottomCardPosition: CGFloat = -150

var body: some View {
    
        ZStack {
            
            MapKitView(isAnnotationSelected: $showAnnotationCard, selectedAnnotation: $annotation)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
            MapCardView(annotation: $annotation)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                .offset(y: (bounds.size.height + bounds.safeAreaInsets.bottom)) //Push the view off the screen on launch
                .offset(y: showAnnotationCard ? kBottomCardPosition : 0) //Push the view back into the visible area if an annotation is selected
                .animation(.spring()) //Animate the change of the offset for the "sliding" effect
                
        }
    }
    
}

struct MapCardView: View {

    @Binding var annotation: MKAnnotation?

    var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
           
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    
                    Text((annotation?.title ?? "") ?? "")
                        .font(.title2).bold()
                    
                    Text((annotation?.subtitle ?? "") ?? "")
                        .font(.caption)
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
            .padding(.leading)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        
    }
}
```

Selecting a different annotation on the map view while MapCardView is still visible will result in the Text views (that show the annotation's title and subtitle) **animating the content change**, if the subsequent text content takes up more width than the previous one. I do not want to see the text change being animated, but rather have it show immediately without an animation.

By using **.animation(nil)** on the Text views in question those views will also stop sliding, and instead appear and dissappear instantly, which is not a wanted behaviour. Is it possible to exclude animations of the content change solely, or do I have to change the way I animate the superview entirely, and be more restrictive in what I animate?

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @Asperi's answer, limiting the animation to only watch for changes on the showAnnotationCard state did stop the text from animating a change to its width when it's already on the screen. However, it still shows the text change animation when the card is first pulled up by selecting an annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try animation with limit to value of state

```
MapCardView(annotation: $annotation)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    .offset(y: (bounds.size.height + bounds.safeAreaInsets.bottom))
    .offset(y: showAnnotationCard ? kBottomCardPosition : 0)
    .animation(.spring(), value: showAnnotationCard)           // << here !!
```

Comment: Thanks @Asperi, it did fix the animation change when I select an annotation while showAnnotationCard = true. However there still is a change animation when I first select an annotation and slide up the card. Do you have any further ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the view that should not have animations.

```
.transaction { transaction in
    transaction.animation = nil
}
```

BWO https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/disable-animations-transactions/